# Global variable keep old value

Tags: javascript, firefox, scope, phaser-framework

Something weird happened .... I used Phaserjs and try to override the Device class :

```
let Device = (function(device)
      {
        return {
            Android :function() {
              return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) == true;
              //return Phaser.Device.Android != undefined;
            },
            BlackBerry: function() {
              return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) == true;
            },
            iOS: function() {
              return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i) == true;
              //return Phaser.Device.iOS == true;
            },
            Opera: function() {
              return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i) == true;
            },
            Windows: function() {
              return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i) == true;
              //return Phaser.Device.WindowsPhone != undefined;
            },
            firefox : function() {
              return navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;
              //return Phaser.Device.Firefox == true;
            },
            any: function() {
              return (Device.Android() || Device.BlackBerry() || Device.iOS() || Device.Opera() || Device.Windows());
            },
            debug: function()
            {
              //console.log("Ios "+Phaser.Device.Firefox+"  Dev:"+Phaser.Device);
              return "Android:"+Device.Android()+" "+
                     "BlackBerry:"+Device.BlackBerry()+" "+
                     "iOS:"+Device.iOS()+" "+
                     "Opera:"+Device.Opera()+" "+
                     "Windows:"+Device.Windows()+" "+
                     "firefox:"+Device.firefox();
            }
          };
        })(Phaser.device);
    export default Device;
```

the Phaser.Device is a singleton and like `$(document).ready` it needs to be initialized first. the function is `Phaser.Device.whenReady(foobar,this);`

The problem is when I call the firefox or iOS function (`Device.iOS()`) I get a old value and not the initialized value (true and false)

I import device like this in a main script :

```
  import Device from './helpers/GameDevice';
```

WHY ? the problem seams to be a problem of scope but I don't know what !

Comment: what is the old value ?

Comment: I am on FF so I must have Firefox: TRUE and iOS:FALSE but I get FF: FALSE and iOS : true , which is illogic !!!

Comment: Browser detection can fail for many reasons, including add ons. navigator.userAgent is a recent thing so it does not always work

Comment: you can contact the creators of phaser here https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/issues

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible to answer without knowing where the old values are set. The Device object only contains functions (not variables) that return a true/false value based on the navigator.userAgent, so are you sure there *are* any old values set anywhere?

Also, have you taken a look at the string value of "navigator.userAgent" on the FireFox browser you are using? Maybe it does not contain the string `firefox` at all?

Detecting browser and OS from the navigator.userAgent string is very tricky. Over the years, navigator.userAgent string has become [unwieldy and very cluttered](http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/), because the major browsers have been forked from the same code base, browser impersonation, backward compatibility etc.

You may want to check out [platform.js](https://github.com/bestiejs/platform.js/), instead of rolling your own.